# Why does the Magento app run so many times?

Tags: magento-1.9

As I've been through debugging a number of issues, I can't help but notice that the same methods get called over and over again. For instance, I ran a stack trace function to log the paths through which the `_initStores()` method in `App.php` gets called when saving from the admin configuration menu, and it turns out that three of the four calls to this function come from the exact same stack of calls.

```
2016-09-15T15:05:11+00:00 DEBUG (7):    1) /www/sites/dev.site.com/files/html/index.php(91): Mage::run('', 'store')
    2) /www/sites/dev.site.com/files/html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    3) /www/sites/dev.site.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
    4) /www/sites/dev.site.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(466): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
2016-09-15T15:05:16+00:00 DEBUG (7):    1) /www/sites/dev.site.com/files/html/index.php(91): Mage::run('', 'store')
    2) /www/sites/dev.site.com/files/html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    3) /www/sites/dev.site.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
    4) /www/sites/dev.site.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(466): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
2016-09-15T15:05:19+00:00 DEBUG (7):    1) /www/sites/dev.site.com/files/html/index.php(91): Mage::run('', 'store')
    2) /www/sites/dev.site.com/files/html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    3) /www/sites/dev.site.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    4) /www/sites/dev.site.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_StandardOverriddenClass->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    5) /www/sites/dev.site.com/files/html/var/cache/ew/files/69/b9/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(273): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
    6) /www/sites/dev.site.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->saveAction()
    7) /www/sites/dev.site.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php(183): Mage_Core_Model_App->reinitStores()
    8) /www/sites/dev.site.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(598): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
2016-09-15T15:05:19+00:00 DEBUG (7):    1) /www/sites/dev.site.com/files/html/index.php(91): Mage::run('', 'store')
    2) /www/sites/dev.site.com/files/html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    3) /www/sites/dev.site.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
    4) /www/sites/dev.site.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(466): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
```

What is the purpose of this running through the same functions so many times? Doesn't this slow down the entire platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the `_initStores` method should run only once per request.
When saving the config section you are actually doing 2 requests.
one POST action to save everything and one GET action to render the page again.
I cannot explain the other 2 requests, but I assume there are 2 ajax requests on that page.
You can easily check this using firebug for firefox or the network tab on the chrome developer tools.

Comment: That makes sense. I appreciate the explanation.